# how can I use param value on the url by using vue router

Tags: vue.js, router

I want to use param value of the url

but the params object is undefined in $router in my case

so how can I use params value

```
<script>
export default{

    data(){
        return{
            item:{},
            
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        console.log(this.$router);
    },
    



}
</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Oup.png)

as you can see of the picture, there is no params object

Comment: ```this.$router``` is wrong, it should be ```this.$route```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get access to params like :

```js
    mounted(){
        console.log(this.$router.currentRoute.params);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the JS it's possible in that way. maybe there would be another solution for that in VUE but by using the JS you can achieve it like this

URL Should be like : http://localhost:4200/stores?key1=value1&key2=value2

```
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
// Display the keys
for (const key of searchParams.keys()) {
  console.log(key);
}
```